# How do you find the equation of this straight line?

Tags: calculus

I am given the following curve--$$4x^3=27y^2$$

I need to find equations of straight lines that are tangent to that curve at one point and normal at another.

How do i proceed with it?

I tried to find $\dfrac{\text{dy}}{\text{d}x}, -\dfrac{\text{dx}}{\text{d}y}$ and compared it with an assumed line $l$ but couldn't do anything meaningful with it.

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Use implicit differentiation to get m = dy/dx.  Then (for tangent) find line with slope m, passing through whatever point you've been given.  For normal, find line with slope -1/m passing through the point.

Comment: @oks i haven't been given any point..

Comment: Just use point $(a,b)$

Comment: And note that you can get $b$ in terms of $a$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

Implicit differentiation gives

$$12x^2 = 54y \cdot y' \Leftrightarrow y' = \frac{12x^2}{54y}$$

For a point $(a,b) = (a, \sqrt{\frac{4}{29}a^3})$ on the line, calculate the slope $y'_{ab}$ of the tangent. Then calculate another point $(c,d)$ for which the normal is $1/y'_{ab}$.

The possible lines from $(a,b)$ to $(c,d)$ are lines satisfying your criteria.